# How to clear the field {pages} for book entries only?

Tags: biblatex

I need to clear the field {pages} for book entries only, so I can't simply use \AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{pages}} since that would remove pages-information from articles as well. I have tried \AtDataInput[book]{\clearfield{pages}} but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

I know that I could simply delete the field in my .bib file, but the database from which I pull entries often contains {pages} for books, so I would prefer a general solution to the problem.

Thank you

Comment: `\AtEveryBibitem{\ifentrytype{book}{\clearfield{pages}}{}}`

Comment: You may want to do this for other entry types (e.g. collection) as well.